# Why are C# calls different for overloaded methods for different values of the same type?

Tags: c#, enums, overloading

I have one doubt concerning c# method overloading and call resolution.

Let's suppose I have the following C# code:

```
enum MyEnum { Value1, Value2 }

public void test() {
    method(0); // this calls method(MyEnum)
    method(1); // this calls method(object)
}

public void method(object o) {
}

public void method(MyEnum e) {
}
```

Note that I know how to make it work but I would like to know why for one value of int (0) it calls one method and for another (1) it calls another. It sounds awkward since both values have the same type (int) but they are "linked" for different methods.

Comment: It applies to this statement also
MyEnum e = 0;   
But You will get compiler error (Explicit conversion required) if write this 
MyEnum e = 1;

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633168/why-does-c-3-allow-the-implicit-conversion-of-literal-zero-0-to-any-enum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Literal `0` is implicitly convertible to any `enum` type, which is a closer match than `object`. [*Spec*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691283%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

See, for example, these [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/03/28/the-root-of-all-evil-part-one.aspx) [posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/03/29/the-root-of-all-evil-part-two.aspx).

Comment: 0 is implicitly convertible to any enum type while 1 isn't!?

Comment: @Galilyou: quote from the C# Language Specification (section 1.10): *"In order for the default value of an enum type to be easily available, the literal 0 implicitly converts to any enum type."*

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure to call

```
public void method(MyEnum e) {
}
```

properly you need to pass in `MyEnum.Value1` or `MyEnum.Value2`.  Enum != int type, hence why you have to cast the int to your enum type.  So `(MyEnum)1` or `(MyEnum)0` would work properly.

In your case, 0 was implicitly cast to your enum type.

Comment: While your answer is (mostly) correct, that was not what the OP asked about.

Comment: I still think it is worth mentioning because it is better for readability to code MyEnum.Value1 than to assume that 0 will implicitly cast it to the enum.  Then you wouldn't have to worry about falling into the wrong overloaded method

Comment: You're right; that is _definitely_ the best practice.  However, it didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Why does C# allow implicit conversion of literal zero to any enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633168/why-does-c-3-allow-the-implicit-conversion-of-literal-zero-0-to-any-enum) is a good reference that has a great answer by JaredPar in it.